# PROJ4 C++ API: Amersfoort RD New to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, wgs84, c++

I try to convert between dutch RD New (EPSG:28992) and WGS84 (EPSG:4326) via PROJ4 C++ API.
On the console this works with:

```
cs2cs +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs +to +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
138494.92605 467792.640021
5d8'46.283"E    52d11'56.38"N 0.000
```

However, doing the same thing in C++ with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <proj_api.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double x = 138494.92605;
  double y = 467792.640021;

  char *srid28992 = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.04,49.91,465.84,-1.9848,1.7439,-9.0587,4.0772 +units=m +no_defs";
  char *srid4326 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";

  projPJ source = pj_init_plus(srid28992);
  projPJ target = pj_init_plus(srid4326);

  if(source==NULL || target==NULL)
    return false;

  x *= DEG_TO_RAD;
  y *= DEG_TO_RAD;

  int success = pj_transform(source, target, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL );

  x *= RAD_TO_DEG;
  y *= RAD_TO_DEG;

  cout << success << endl << x << endl << y << endl;
}
```

results in wrong numbers:

```
./main 
0
3.34135
48.0483
```

I wasn't able to find a working example for this. What am I missing here?

PROJ4 Version is 4.6.1

Comment: Why don't you have the towgs84 parameter in the cs2cs version?

Comment: Hm, seems I forgot it there. But that doesn't change anything. See the solving answer below.

Comment: @t1mg: Hi! I had problems building your program. After I finally did it, I summarized my solution here: https://github.com/thomasfermi/proj4_cmake_example 
Please let me know if you are not ok with me using your sample program in that github repo. The repo is mainly about the CMake and vcpkg troubles and not the actual program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source (inputs) are not in degrees. You shouldn't convert them before the pj_transform() call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <proj_api.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double x = 138494.92605;
  double y = 467792.640021;

  char *srid28992 = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.04,49.91,465.84,-1.9848,1.7439,-9.0587,4.0772 +units=m +no_defs";
  char *srid4326 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";

  projPJ source = pj_init_plus(srid28992);
  projPJ target = pj_init_plus(srid4326);

  if(source==NULL || target==NULL)
    return false;

//  x *= DEG_TO_RAD;
//  y *= DEG_TO_RAD;

  int success = pj_transform(source, target, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL );

  x *= RAD_TO_DEG;
  y *= RAD_TO_DEG;

  cout << success << endl << x << endl << y << endl;
}
```

Then building and running it:

```
$ g++ -Wall -W test.cc -lproj
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:11:21: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
test.cc:12:20: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
bradh@ornata:~/proj4$ ./a.out 
0
5.14431
52.1976
```

Comment: Thanks! Totally makes sense, since RD doesn't use angles.